# Power Query - How to access SharePoint library contents by its "display name" instead of its "internal name"

Tags: sharepoint, powerquery

I have a SharePoint site with libraries. I want to import some contents through Power Query.
The problem is when I call Sharepoint.Contents() the column name contains the internal name of the library. This name is often different than the name displayed in the site. For example the special characters are deleted, or the name is followed by a number. This is a problem to set up a standardized process.

How can I access the content by specifying the display name instead of the internal name?

I tried to use Sharepoint.Contents() but it contains only the library internal name.
I tried to use Sharepoint.Tables() which contains the library "display name", but I don't find the way to access the content of the library.
I want both access the content and specifying the display name instead of internal name.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching to `[ApiVersion = 14])` - it shows the display name **but** with all whitespace removed. Will that do for your need?

Alternative method via OData - try:

```
let
    Source = OData.Feed("https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites|teams/yyy/_api/web/folders", null, [Implementation="2.0"]),
    #"Expanded Properties" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Source, "Properties", {"vti_listtitle"}, {"Display Name"})
in
    #"Expanded Properties"
```

This will give you the internal name and Display name of each Library.

Comment: Sadly not. I tried but i get an empty list. The microsoft documentation says the ApiVersion should be 15 for non english Sharepoint site, maybe it's the reason.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the intenal name ?

Comment: Yes, via Sharepoint Designer or PNP PowerShell: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/change-sharepoint-online-list-or-library-internal-name

Comment: Updated answer above with an alternative method, via OData

Comment: Waouh ! It works perfectly !
Thank you so much, i spent some hours searching for a solution...

Comment: i don't know anything about OData neither what it's possible to find in the file sructure after "/_api". Is there a blog or something i can read about this ?